# Kendo UI Angular 2 Sortable Methods

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

How does one use the [Methods](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/sortable/api/SortableComponent/#toc-methods) of Kendo UI for Angular 2's [Sortable](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/sortable/) component?

The documentation doesn't present any specific examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering for future users.

**Import**:

```
import {SortableComponent} from '@progress/kendo-angular-sortable';
```

**Include**:

```
export class ComponentName implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('sortable') public sortable: SortableComponent;
    ...

}
```

**Call**:

```
public addDataItemFunction() {
    this.sortable.addDataItem('1', 0);
}
```

"addDataItem" being the Method.

**Element**:

```
<kendo-sortable #sortable ...></kendo-sortable>
```

Hope this helps.